# MongoDB: mapping collection names for user

Tags: mongodb

I have a following corner-case for MongoDB that I hope you can help me to solve.

My MongoDB database is used by multiple independent users and there's a technical limitations that holds me from creating a DB per user. Users are untrusted. Users will create collections with arbitrary names.

Is there any way to "namespace" the collections of one user from the collections of the other user? For example, when user "jim" makes a collection "orders" it will not clash with user "bob" creating collection "orders".

Users are authenticated and connected through SSL-protected channel.

Comment: Are these MongoDB users or users of an application?

Comment: They are MongoDB users

Answer (score 1):

Don't create these many collections in DB. In one collection you maintain that collection fields in one document. So, you will be able to access all the collection by "_id" unique field. And all documents fields and values will be according to user choice.

For example you have one collection "user_collection" which stores all the collection details of users.

```
user_collection
{
 { "_id" : "0921092109227812",
   "collectionName": "orders",
   "user": ObjectId(Ref_Id1),
   "fields": []
 },
 { "_id" : "5686565681232344",
   "collectionName": "orders",
   "user": ObjectId(Ref_Id2),
   "fields": []
 }
}
```

I have just given you the schema. You can elaborate this schema according to your requirements.

Comment: Users cannot be told to write to the specific collection. Unfortunately this answer doesn't meet the tech limitations.